# Meaning of digits after NaN in Python Decimal object

Tags: python

I was reading the lexical definition for valid decimal string syntax in the documentation for [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) and the following struck me as kind of odd:

```
nan            ::=  'NaN' [digits] | 'sNaN' [digits]
```

This looked really strange to me, but apparently digits can be included after 'NaN' without any issues, but any character besides digits after 'NaN' raises `InvalidOperation`.

```
>>> Decimal('NaN10')
Decimal('NaN10')
```

So I have a few questions about this:

1. What is the meaning of digits that are a part of `NaN`?
2. How do instances of `NaN` with digits behave differently than a "normal" `NaN`?
3. Are there ways to obtain a `NaN` with digits besides initializing it that way?
4. Are there other places in Python besides the `Decimal` class where `NaN` can be followed by digits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an [IEEE-754 feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard#Formats) to distinguish between different kinds of NaNs (the "payload"). The digits are encoded into the mantissa of the number:

```
>>> Decimal("NaN456").as_tuple()
DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(4, 5, 6), exponent='n')
>>> Decimal("NaN123").as_tuple()
DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(1, 2, 3), exponent='n')
>>> Decimal("NaN").as_tuple()
DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(), exponent='n')
```

The sole purpose of the payload is for diagnosis. These NaNs are no different from "normal" NaNs.